How do I add an Angular v.17 Elements component to an ASP.Net webforms app?
I have an ASP.Net Webforms app running .Net 4.5.
I've built an Angular v.17 app with Angular Elements and an Angular Materials Table following this tutorial as a model of the Angular Elements portion: https://angularindepth.com/posts/1116/angular-web-components-a-complete-guide.
Following the example here is my Angular.json:
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "MatTableElements": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss",
          "standalone": false
        },
        "@schematics/angular:directive": {
          "standalone": false
        },
        "@schematics/angular:pipe": {
          "standalone": false
        }
      },
      "root": "projects/mat-table-elements",
      "sourceRoot": "projects/mat-table-elements/src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:application",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/mat-table-elements",
            "index": "projects/mat-table-elements/src/index.html",
            "browser": "projects/mat-table-elements/src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "projects/mat-table-elements/tsconfig.app.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "projects/mat-table-elements/src/favicon.ico",
              "projects/mat-table-elements/src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "projects/mat-table-elements/src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "1500kb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "none",
              "optimization": {
                "scripts": true,
                "styles": {
                  "minify": true,
                  "inlineCritical": false
                },
                "fonts": true
              }
            },
            "development": {
              "optimization": false,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "buildTarget": "MatTableElements:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildTarget": "MatTableElements:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "buildTarget": "MatTableElements:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js",
              "zone.js/testing"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "projects/mat-table-elements/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "projects/mat-table-elements/src/favicon.ico",
              "projects/mat-table-elements/src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "projects/mat-table-elements/src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

And here my app.module.ts.  *Please note I am not using standalone components:
import { NgModule, DoBootstrap, Injector, ApplicationRef } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { createCustomElement } from "@angular/elements";


import { ItemAssignmentsComponent } from './item-assignments/item-assignments.component';
import { provideAnimationsAsync } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations/async';
import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material/table';
import { MatPaginatorModule } from '@angular/material/paginator';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ItemAssignmentsComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatPaginatorModule
  ],
  providers: [
    provideAnimationsAsync()
  ]
  // entryComponents: [ItemAssignmentsComponent]
})
export class AppModule implements DoBootstrap { 
  constructor(private injector: Injector) {
    const el = createCustomElement(ItemAssignmentsComponent, {injector});
    customElements.define('item-assignment', el);
  }

  ngDoBootstrap(appRef: ApplicationRef): void {
      
  }

}


I use the CLI to build the app,

Then load the Javascript libraries and Styles into my ASP.Net webforms app, calling the scripts and the custom tag in the page:

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="Server">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/moog-default.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/moog-layout.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/js/item-data-report/styles.css" />

    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/item-data-report/chunk-HH4V2P6H.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/item-data-report/chunk-OH42BLK4.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/item-data-report/main.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/item-data-report/polyfills.js"></script>
    
    
    <item-assignment></item-assignment>
</asp:Content>

However, upon running the webforms app I get these errors in my browser console:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'        chunk-HH4V2P6H.js:7
Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module        chunk-OH42BLK4.js:1
Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module        main.js:1

Is there an error in my Angular setup?  Or is there something I am missing in trying to import the Angular Element into my ASP.Net webform?
EDIT: Adding tsconfig.json:
/* To learn more about this file see: https://angular.io/config/tsconfig. */
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitOverride": true,
    "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "ES2022",
    "module": "ES2022",
    "useDefineForClassFields": false,
    "lib": [
      "ES2022",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
    "strictTemplates": true
  }
}

Update 1:
Went ahead and rebuilt this as a standalone following https://www.angulararchitects.io/blog/angular-elements-web-components-with-standalone-components/ as a guide.
However, still receiving the error above from the ASP.net page about not being able to use export outside of of a module.
New tsconfig.json:
/* To learn more about this file see: https://angular.io/config/tsconfig. */
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitOverride": true,
    "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "ES2022",
    "module": "ES2022",
    "useDefineForClassFields": false,
    "lib": [
      "ES2022",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
    "strictTemplates": true
  }
}



Can you also include your tsconfig.json?

Added the tsconfig.json.

@OctavianM, any further thoughts on this?
